# How to find out available space in linux kernel space?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, vfs

My need is to add a available space check in *vfs_writeev*. if available space on VFS is under 1GB, then forbidden the writting operation.

So my question is, how to find out available space in linux kernel struct ?

Any reply will be appreciated, thank you !

```
ssize_t vfs_writev(struct file *file, const struct iovec __user *vec,
           unsigned long vlen, loff_t *pos, int flags)
{
    struct iovec iovstack[UIO_FASTIOV];
    struct iovec *iov = iovstack;
    struct iov_iter iter;
    ssize_t ret;

    ret = import_iovec(WRITE, vec, vlen, ARRAY_SIZE(iovstack), &iov, &iter);
    if (ret >= 0) {
        file_start_write(file);
        ret = do_iter_write(file, &iter, pos, flags);
        file_end_write(file);
        kfree(iov);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Run `strace df .` -> See that it uses `statfs()` -> Find `sys_statfs()` in the kernel sources -> Read the code.

Comment: Thanks very much. I found out that in super_block struct, there is a super_operations member, in which the function (int (*statfs)) (struct dentry *, struct kstatfs *) can collect the information about a specified dentry, which can be given by the root dentry of the filesystem.